# Find path of occurrences of a key, value pair in nested dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, dictionary, path, nested, nested-lists

I got a json structure with inside a dictionary of strings, lists, dictionaries and list of dictionaries. the depth is arbitrary but all dictionaries do have a key of "name".

I need to do two things.
1) find all key values of a certain key, I got this working with the below but it seems clunky...

```
def find_all_keys(db, search_key):
    key_found_list = []
    for key, value in db.items():
        if key == search_key:
            key_found_list.append(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            resultsA = find_all_keys(value, search_key)
            for result in resultsA:
                key_found_list.append(result)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    resultsB = find_all_keys(item, search_key)
                    for result_outofnames in resultsB:
                        key_found_list.append(result_outofnames)
    return key_found_list
```

for the second part.

Every level of the dictionary has a attribute called name, which is a string.

I’m trying to look for the value of a certain name and if it’s found find all other values of “name” before that.

So for example key "name" and "value" some321 should return a list of the path as example: 
md -> level0 -> level1 -> be -> some321

filling a list on first hit seems relative easy, but i'm unable to get my head around only filling the list if the result is found. Any ideas of a good approach I can take?

below one of my many failed attempts:

```
def find_key_value_path(db, search_key, search_value):
    key_value_path_list = []
    for key, value in db.items():
        if key == search_key:
            print("found key: ", key)
            if value == search_value:
                print("found value in key", value, key)
                key_value_path_list.append(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            results = find_key_value_path(value, search_key)
            for result in results:
                key_value_path_list.append(result)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = find_key_value_path(item, search_key)
                    for another_result in more_results:
                        key_value_path_list.append(another_result)
    return key_value_path_list
```

Sorry adding an example of a json input:

```json
{
  "name": "/", 
  "device_count": 91, 
  "num_ports": 3, 
  "devices": [], 
  "childnodes": [
    {
      "name": "mm", 
      "device_count": 0, 
      "num_ports": 3, 
      "devices": [], 
      "childnodes": [
        {
          "name": "mynode", 
          "device_count": 0, 
          "num_ports": 3, 
          "devices": [], 
          "childnodes": [], 
          "type": "group"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "group"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "md", 
      "device_count": 91, 
      "num_ports": 4, 
      "devices": [], 
      "childnodes": [
        {
          "name": “level0, 
          "device_count": 91, 
          "num_ports": 4, 
          "devices": [], 
          "childnodes": [
            {
              "name": "level1”, 
              "device_count": 6, 
              "num_ports": 6, 
              "devices": [], 
              "childnodes": [
                {
                  "name": "level2”, 
                  "device_count": 2, 
                  "num_ports": 6, 
                  "devices": [
                    {
                      "name": “something1”, 
                      "longitude": "", 
                      "mac": "00:1a:1e:04:a9:d0", 
                      "num_ports": 6, 
                      "latitude": "", 
                      "type": "A7240XM"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "name": “something2”, 
                      "longitude": "", 
                      "mac": "00:1a:1e:04:aa:d0", 
                      "num_ports": 6, 
                      "latitude": "", 
                      "type": "A7240XM"
                    }
                  ], 
                  "childnodes": [], 
                  "type": "group"
                }, 
                {
                  "name": "ng", 
                  "device_count": 2, 
                  "num_ports": 6, 
                  "devices": [
                    {
                      "name": “someother1”, 
                      "longitude": "", 
                      "mac": "00:1a:1e:05:4e:b8", 
                      "num_ports": 6, 
                      "latitude": "", 
                      "type": "A7240XM"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "name": “findME, 
                      "longitude": "", 
                      "mac": "00:1a:1e:05:4d:e8", 
                      "num_ports": 6, 
                      "latitude": "", 
                      "type": "A7240XM"
                    }
                  ], 
                  "childnodes": [], 
                  "type": "group"
                }, 
                {
                  "name": “be”, 
                  "device_count": 2, 
                  "num_ports": 6, 
                  "devices": [
                    {
                      "name": “some123”, 
                      "longitude": "", 
                      "mac": "00:1a:1e:05:4e:b8", 
                      "num_ports": 6, 
                      "latitude": "", 
                      "type": "A7240XM"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "name": “some321”, 
                      "longitude": "", 
                      "mac": "00:1a:1e:05:4d:e8", 
                      "num_ports": 6, 
                      "latitude": "", 
                      "type": "A7240XM"
                    }
                  ], 
                  "childnodes": [], 
                  "type": "group"
                },
```

Comment: You have a bunch of invalid quotes in your example and it doesn't properly close braces so it's essentially unusable without more work than most people will be willing to put in to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use yield to create an iterator.  It would make the code simpler and more efficient (Especially if you're not going to always go through all occurrences).  To only find the first one, you can use the next function.

```
def findKeys(d,key,value):
    if key in d and d[key] == value: yield [d["name"]]
    subLevels = ( (a,v) for a,vl in d.items() if isinstance(vl,list) for v in vl )
    for attrib,subDict in subLevels:
        if not isinstance(subDict,dict):continue
        for path in findKeys(subDict,key,value):
            yield [d["name"]]+path
```

output:

```
for path in findKeys(d,"type","A7240XM"):
    print(path)

['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'level2', 'something1']
['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'level2', 'something2']
['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'ng', 'someother1']
['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'ng', 'findME']
['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'be', 'some123']
['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'be', 'some321']
```

]

```
next(findKeys(d,"name","some123"))

['/', 'md', 'level0', 'level1', 'be', 'some123']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great.
I'm still trying to get my head around your sublevel line and the continue line. but will break it down in smaller parts to see how it's working.